# Running Cuda with CMake on AWS EC2 (Amazon cloud) with Nvidia GRID K520

Tags: amazon-ec2, cuda, cmake, nvcc, nsight

Some time ago I setup a g2 GPU instance on Amazon Cloud. This instance has **NVIDIA GRID K520 with WDDM driver** model (you can see that on Nsight overview or if you use GPU-Z utility app).

Unfortunately, my CUDA code DID NOT run on this card/instance and as I new EC2 user I was afraid that there is something wrong with the hardware or the remote session. This is because my **CMake** C++/Cuda project was building fine. Although, when I was running/debugging I was getting no response from the GPUs.

Apparently, I found out that I was not using the correct Cuda architecture flag and I had to add **-gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35**. After adding this everything run fine. I hope you find useful my silly mistake.

Comment: How are you accessing the G2 instance? Via remote desktop?

Comment: Via Microsoft Remote Desktop (RDP)

Comment: OK that's your problem. RDP runs in Session 0 and doesn't have privileges to access the WDDM driver. You need to use something else instead, or switch to the TCC driver.

Comment: @talonmies I have tried VNC, Slashtop and TeamViewer and it didn't work. Could it be anything else?

Comment: What operating system are you running?

Comment: Win12 RC2 is the server and I access the remote via MacOSX. I was running via RDP CUDA on Tesla cards without any problem for 5Y. Is this because of the TCC in that case?

Comment: Yes, TCC devices are not subject to the same limitation as WDDM devices.  Whatever login method you use (ssh or vnc or whatever), must run as a process rather than a service. If you run as a service, you will have the same Session 0 isolation problem as RDP and it won't work. Beyond that, I can't suggest anything else, I have no experience with Windows on AWS.

Comment: Would it help to setup a Linux AWS instance with VNC ??

Comment: There are some known issues with the CUDA 7.5 release driver running on AWS, whereas 7.0 works fine AFAIK, but otherwise Linux has no WDDM style limitations and any access method (ssh, vnc, nxclient) should work. Obviously you have no access to Direct3D or any of the Windows only APIs, if that's important to you. Caveat to add that I have never used Grid K520 AWS instance, only the older Telsa instances, but [someone else seems to have got it to work](http://tleyden.github.io/blog/2014/10/25/cuda-6-dot-5-on-aws-gpu-instance-running-ubuntu-14-dot-04/)

Comment: Apologies for not posting earlier, but apparently I had a mistake on my Cmake files. I had the add the right architecture flags into it (e.g. -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35). Sorry for the confusion.